# Tagging Jenkins builds with git

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, tagging

I have already looked through a few Stack overflow posts on this but I still cannot find an answer.

My company uses Jenkins we have recently moved from SVN to a GIT which is hosted on one of our servers.

With the SVN we were able to select a build we had already made, choose a tag name and tag it then these changes would be added to the repository.

Unfortunately when we tag with git the tag is not pushed up to the repository, also we don't have a way of setting the remote push url.

Any suggestions, I have tried Git publisher + post build step, which is not ideal as we don't want to push a tag for ever build + we would like to have control over the naming scheme of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this tutorial](http://www.benhallbenhall.com/2013/03/hudson-jenkins-create-git-tags-branches-automatically/) . Let me know if that helps

Alternatively, you can write your own custom batch or bash script to perform the tag.
You can then trigger it on specific builds using [Promoted Builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) plugin (bundled with default Jenkins installation).

Comment: I have tried git publisher and unfortunately it can not be used for my company as a solution. We want to tag builds on demand with custom tag names like we could with SVN. The git publisher plugin tags every build you make.

Comment: You can always write your own batch/bash script to do the tagging (lots of SVN information is available at job runtime through environment variables), and then use [Promoted Builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) plugin to initiate on-demand tagging. I actually tag my SVN builds with promotions running custom batch script.

Comment: that was the conclusion I was coming to, put that in an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I don't know about Git, but if a build uses Subversion, when you look at a particular build, there's a link in the left hand column to tag that build. Is there a similar link for Git-based projects? Take a look at the build you want to tag and see if there's a _Tag this build_ link.